# Clojure - Alternative to using reduction on large map or ways to improve performance

Tags: clojure

I have a moderate sized map (~1M keys with relatively small values e.g. `(first mymap) => ["7:21658846-21658846" {["C" "T"] {"central_nervous_system" 1}}]`) which is reduced to another map using the functions below (some secondary funcctions omitted because they aren't really relevant to the question - they are not impacting performance)

The new map is created using reduction (reduce-kv) because I need to cumulatively increase various nested values in the map as I parse each element from the original map.

This is not really a problem for about 100K entries, which takes about 40 seconds. It is a massive problem for my 1M size map (which is only going to get bigger with future runs) which hasnt finished yet after 20 mins.

Is there any obvious issues which are easily addressed? non-idiomatic approaches which can be changed to drastically improve performance? It doesn't seem particularly parallizable - but something in there is really inefficient - I expect the cumulative map.

Any advice appreciated.

*Edit - added assoc-in-sum defn

```
(defn add-mut-freq-firstTS
  "Builds a map of Transcript -> {aapos -> {:aaposn_count :codon :aa {genomic_SNP_posn -> {:SNP_posn_count :frame {:genomic_ref :genomic_mut :SNP_count :aa_mut :codon_mut}}}}.
  but only using one transcript per SNP. ***ONLY USED FOR STATS CALCS***"
  [CDS-ref snp-freq]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k v](let [aa-ref (first (cosu/map-ts-aa-pos CDS-ref [k v]))] (add-mut-freq** m aa-ref aa-ref [k v]))) {} snp-freq) )

(defn add-mut-freq**
  "Adds data for frequency of different mutations at a given position to a     cumulative map m for a given transcript. Updates running totals
  for frequency at aa position and genomic position as well."
  [m ts first-ts snp-freq]
  (let [[ts_ID SNP_aa_posn SNP_aa_frame _ gene strand] ts
    [posn nt-mut-freq] snp-freq
    m-pre (if (= ts first-ts) (assoc-in m [:ts ts_ID :snp-aa-pos SNP_aa_posn :snp-nt-posn posn :first] true) m)
    m-init (assoc-in m-pre [:ts ts_ID :gene] gene)]
(reduce-kv (fn [m1 k v](
          let [mut k
               tiss-freq v
               snp-count (apply + (vals tiss-freq))]
                     (-> m1 (u/assoc-in-sum [:ts ts_ID :ts-cnt] snp-count)
                         (assoc-in [:ts ts_ID :ts-strand] strand)
                         (u/assoc-in-sum [:ts ts_ID :snp-aa-pos SNP_aa_posn :aa-cnt] snp-count)
                         (u/assoc-in-sum [:ts ts_ID :snp-aa-pos SNP_aa_posn :snp-nt-posn posn :pos-cnt] snp-count)
                         (assoc-in [:ts ts_ID :snp-aa-pos SNP_aa_posn :snp-nt-posn posn :ts-frame] SNP_aa_frame)
                         (u/assoc-in-sum [:ts ts_ID :snp-aa-pos SNP_aa_posn :snp-nt-posn posn :mut-nt mut :posnt-cnt] snp-count)
                         (add-tissue-counts ts_ID SNP_aa_posn tiss-freq)
                         (assoc-in [:ts ts_ID :snp-aa-pos SNP_aa_posn :snp-nt-posn posn :mut-nt mut :mut-tiss-freq] tiss-freq))
          )) m-init nt-mut-freq)))

(defn add-tissue-counts
  [m ts_ID SNP_aa_posn tiss-map]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m1 k v] (-> m1 (u/assoc-in-sum [:ts ts_ID :snp-aa-pos SNP_aa_posn :aa-tiss-cnt k] v)
           (u/assoc-in-sum [:ts ts_ID :ts-tiss-cnt k] v)
           (u/assoc-in-sum [:tiss-cnt k] v)
           )) m tiss-map))

(defn assoc-in-sum
  "Same as assoc-in except that if the key already exists, the value is added to instead of replaced"
  [m key-vec v]
  (let [ex-val (get-in m key-vec)
        new-val (if ex-val (+ ex-val v) v)]
  (assoc-in m key-vec new-val))
  )
```

Comment: One low hanging fruit is that you are performing many assoc-in(-sum) on paths with shares a common prefix. You should group them into an update-in on the common prefix and unroll the remaining `*-in` calls. Also `assoc-in-sum` is `(udpate-in m ks (fnil + 0) v)`.

Comment: just glanced over it, maybe its time for [*warn-on-reflection*](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*warn-on-reflection*)

Comment: @birdspider You will get zero warnings: there is no java interop happening here at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a ton of reductions over reductions on top of persistent data and the speed could be improved by using a stateful transducer.

Here's a little example for how to create transformer function using volatiles, maybe it could give some ideas for creating a faster version of your code.

```clojure
(defn test-xf
  [rf]
  (let [sum (volatile! 0)]
    (fn
      ([] (rf))

      ([result] (rf (assoc! result :total-sum @sum)))

      ([result [k m]]

        ;; calculate sums etc.
       (vswap! sum + (get-in m [["C" "T"] "x"]))

        ;; Result is transient map while in reduction!
       (-> result
           (assoc! :mydata "hello")
           (assoc! k m))
        ))))

(defn data [n] 
  (for [i (range n)]
    [(str "key-" i) {["C" "T"] {"x" 1}}]))

(time
  (:total-sum
    (into {} test-xf (data 1000000))))

"Elapsed time: 1750.867127 msecs"
=> 1000000
```

Comment: For others reading this - some good articles on the subject that helped me; http://insideclojure.org/2014/12/18/interpose/ http://insideclojure.org/2014/12/17/distinct-transducer/

Comment: [Tesser](https://github.com/aphyr/tesser) might also be interesting library to check out. Many things of what it does can be done using core libraries, but it has a good readme text explaining key concepts behind folding and parallel processing of datasets.

Comment: OK - in the end, stateful transducers are cool, and I learned from the experience, but were not really helpful in this case. The reason is that there are a lot of running sums to keep (the purpose of the map) and implementing the transducers were of negligible benefit. Upvote for the info and suggestion as I have learned a lot from chasing the bunny down that particular hole, but cant mark it as an answer in this case. Thanks mangolas

Comment: @statler ok, nice to hear that at least it was a learning experience. Apart from being (sometimes) faster transducers compose very nicely, it might be possible to separate calculations to different functions and make things easier to follow and find the bottleneck. Good luck anyways.